# Unable to reference a package

Tags: haskell, pandoc

I'm failing to run (or compile) a simple script due to a reportedly missing `Text.Pandoc.JSON` dependency. This question is similar to another one: [Pandoc 'Could not find module ...' for installed module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21273070/pandoc-could-not-find-module-for-installed-module)

Here's the script:

```
import Text.Pandoc.JSON

pagebreakXml :: String
pagebreakXml = "<w:p><w:r><w:br w:type=\"page\"/></w:r></w:p>"

pagebreakBlock :: Block
pagebreakBlock = RawBlock (Format "openxml") pagebreakXml

blockSwapper :: Block -> Block
blockSwapper (Para [Str "<div class=\"docxPageBreak\"></div>"])  = pagebreakBlock
blockSwapper blk = blk

main = toJSONFilter blockSwapper
```

In order to compile it, I installed Haskell as well as `pandoc` package like this:

```
$ curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://get-ghcup.haskell.org | sh
$ cabal install pandoc
```

Installation took roughly 20 minutes.

Now, when I try to run it, I get this:

```
$ runghc -v docx-page-filter.hs
Glasgow Haskell Compiler, Version 8.8.3, stage 2 booted by GHC version 8.6.3
Using binary package database: /Users/eugene/.ghcup/ghc/8.8.3/lib/ghc-8.8.3/package.conf.d/package.cache
package flags []
loading package database /Users/eugene/.ghcup/ghc/8.8.3/lib/ghc-8.8.3/package.conf.d
wired-in package ghc-prim mapped to ghc-prim-0.5.3
wired-in package integer-wired-in mapped to integer-gmp-1.0.2.0
wired-in package base mapped to base-4.13.0.0
wired-in package rts mapped to rts
wired-in package template-haskell mapped to template-haskell-2.15.0.0
wired-in package ghc mapped to ghc-8.8.3
package flags []
loading package database /Users/eugene/.ghcup/ghc/8.8.3/lib/ghc-8.8.3/package.conf.d
wired-in package ghc-prim mapped to ghc-prim-0.5.3
wired-in package integer-wired-in mapped to integer-gmp-1.0.2.0
wired-in package base mapped to base-4.13.0.0
wired-in package rts mapped to rts-1.0
wired-in package template-haskell mapped to template-haskell-2.15.0.0
wired-in package ghc mapped to ghc-8.8.3
*** Desugar:
*** Simplify [expr]:
!!! Simplify [expr]: finished in 0.18 milliseconds, allocated 0.056 megabytes
*** CorePrep [expr]:
!!! CorePrep [expr]: finished in 3.22 milliseconds, allocated 1.706 megabytes
*** ByteCodeGen [Ghci1]:
!!! ByteCodeGen [Ghci1]: finished in 0.11 milliseconds, allocated 0.029 megabytes
Loading package ghc-prim-0.5.3 ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp-1.0.2.0 ... linking ... done.
*** gcc:
gcc -DTABLES_NEXT_TO_CODE -B/Users/eugene/.ghcup/ghc/8.8.3/lib/ghc-8.8.3/base-4.13.0.0 --print-file-name libiconv.dylib
*** gcc:
gcc -DTABLES_NEXT_TO_CODE -B/Users/eugene/.ghcup/ghc/8.8.3/lib/ghc-8.8.3/base-4.13.0.0 --print-file-name liblibiconv.dylib
*** gcc:
gcc -DTABLES_NEXT_TO_CODE -B/Users/eugene/.ghcup/ghc/8.8.3/lib/ghc-8.8.3/base-4.13.0.0 --print-file-name iconv.lib
*** gcc:
gcc -DTABLES_NEXT_TO_CODE -B/Users/eugene/.ghcup/ghc/8.8.3/lib/ghc-8.8.3/base-4.13.0.0 --print-file-name libiconv.lib
*** gcc:
gcc -DTABLES_NEXT_TO_CODE -B/Users/eugene/.ghcup/ghc/8.8.3/lib/ghc-8.8.3/base-4.13.0.0 --print-file-name libiconv.dll.a
*** gcc:
gcc -DTABLES_NEXT_TO_CODE -B/Users/eugene/.ghcup/ghc/8.8.3/lib/ghc-8.8.3/base-4.13.0.0 --print-file-name iconv.dll.a
*** gcc:
gcc -DTABLES_NEXT_TO_CODE -B/Users/eugene/.ghcup/ghc/8.8.3/lib/ghc-8.8.3/base-4.13.0.0 --print-file-name libiconv.a
*** gcc:
gcc -DTABLES_NEXT_TO_CODE -B/Users/eugene/.ghcup/ghc/8.8.3/lib/ghc-8.8.3/base-4.13.0.0 --print-file-name iconv.a
*** gcc:
gcc -DTABLES_NEXT_TO_CODE -B/Users/eugene/.ghcup/ghc/8.8.3/lib/ghc-8.8.3/base-4.13.0.0 --print-file-name libiconv
*** gcc:
gcc -DTABLES_NEXT_TO_CODE -B/Users/eugene/.ghcup/ghc/8.8.3/lib/ghc-8.8.3/base-4.13.0.0 --print-file-name iconv
Loading package base-4.13.0.0 ... linking ... done.
Search directories (user):
Search directories (gcc):
*** Desugar:
*** Simplify [expr]:
!!! Simplify [expr]: finished in 0.07 milliseconds, allocated 0.044 megabytes
*** CorePrep [expr]:
!!! CorePrep [expr]: finished in 0.03 milliseconds, allocated 0.014 megabytes
*** ByteCodeGen [Ghci1]:
!!! ByteCodeGen [Ghci1]: finished in 0.05 milliseconds, allocated 0.028 megabytes
*** Desugar:
*** Simplify [expr]:
!!! Simplify [expr]: finished in 0.10 milliseconds, allocated 0.061 megabytes
*** CorePrep [expr]:
!!! CorePrep [expr]: finished in 0.04 milliseconds, allocated 0.022 megabytes
*** ByteCodeGen [Ghci1]:
!!! ByteCodeGen [Ghci1]: finished in 0.11 milliseconds, allocated 0.065 megabytes
*** Chasing dependencies:
Chasing modules from:
!!! Chasing dependencies: finished in 0.04 milliseconds, allocated 0.021 megabytes
Stable obj: {}
Stable BCO: {}
unload: retaining objs []
unload: retaining bcos []
Ready for upsweep []
Upsweep completely successful.
*** Deleting temp files:
Deleting:
*** Chasing dependencies:
Chasing modules from: *docx-page-filter.hs
!!! Chasing dependencies: finished in 0.60 milliseconds, allocated 0.334 megabytes
Stable obj: {}
Stable BCO: {}
unload: retaining objs []
unload: retaining bcos []
Ready for upsweep
  [NONREC
      ModSummary {
         ms_hs_date = 2020-07-01 09:51:29.83381948 UTC
         ms_mod = Main,
         ms_textual_imps = [(Nothing, Prelude), (Nothing, Text.Pandoc.JSON)]
         ms_srcimps = []
      }]
*** Deleting temp files:
Deleting:
compile: input file docx-page-filter.hs
*** Checking old interface for Main (use -ddump-hi-diffs for more details):
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( docx-page-filter.hs, interpreted )
*** Parser [Main]:
!!! Parser [Main]: finished in 0.35 milliseconds, allocated 0.332 megabytes
*** Renamer/typechecker [Main]:
!!! Renamer/typechecker [Main]: finished in 1.57 milliseconds, allocated 0.021 megabytes

docx-page-filter.hs:1:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘Text.Pandoc.JSON’
    Locations searched:
      Text/Pandoc/JSON.hs
      Text/Pandoc/JSON.lhs
      Text/Pandoc/JSON.hsig
      Text/Pandoc/JSON.lhsig
  |
1 | import Text.Pandoc.JSON
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Upsweep partially successful.
*** Deleting temp files:
Deleting:
Failed, no modules loaded.
*** Deleting temp files:
Deleting:
*** Deleting temp dirs:
Deleting:
$
```

When I try to compile it via `ghc --make -v docx-page-filter.hs`, I get a similar output.

Things I've noticed that might be of help:

- the output above contains these lines:

  ```
  Search directories (user):
  Search directories (gcc):
  ```

  **Does this mean the installed libraries are not in a compiler's *search path*?** Is it possible to manually tell the compiler where to look for the packages?
- The following commands output nothing:

  ```
  $ cabal list --installed | grep pandoc
  $
  $ ghc-pkg list | grep pandoc
  $
  ```

  However, running the following reveals `pandoc`:

  ```
  $ ls -l /Users/eugene/.cabal/store/ghc-8.8.3/ | grep pndc
  drwxr-xr-x    5 eugene  staff   160 Jul  1 15:07 pndc-2.10-1cd05aed
  drwxr-xr-x    5 eugene  staff   160 Jul  1 15:07 pndc-2.10-e61ae373
  drwxr-xr-x    5 eugene  staff   160 Jul  1 14:52 pndc-typs-1.21-39168129
  $
  ```
- Attempts to install or re-install `pandoc` result in a no-op:

  ```
  $ cabal install pandoc
  Resolving dependencies...
  Up to date
  Symlinking 'pandoc'
  $
  $ cabal install pandoc --reinstall
  Resolving dependencies...
  Up to date
  Symlinking 'pandoc'
  $
  ```

**Can someone spot what am I doing wrong?** I don't need a `cabal.project` file or anything, my need is to compile a single file and go with it. But I can try and explore `cabal.project`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few rounds of Googling made me realize that in order to specify a path to packages, [`-package-db`](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/packages.html#ghc-flag--package-db%20%E2%9F%A8file%E2%9F%A9) option must be used.

In my case, in order to compile the file, I had to do this:

```
ghc --make -v docx-page-filter.hs -package-db=/Users/eugene/.cabal/store/ghc-8.8.3/package.db
```

More on the matter in an excellent answer to a question here: [Cabal cannot find locally sourced (yet correctly installed) packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60650929/cabal-cannot-find-locally-sourced-yet-correctly-installed-packages)